# Can I legally cross the border from the US to Canada on a J-1 visa?

Tags: visas, canada, j1-visas, brazilian-citizens

I'll be living in Seattle and I want to regularly visit Vancouver. I'll be on an au pair (J-1) visa. I'm Brazilian.

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: My nationality is Brazilian

Comment: According to [http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp), you will need a Canadian visa to enter Canada.

Comment: What type of visa you need will, of course, depend on  what you will be doing in Canada. Tourist? Working?...

Comment: As a general principle, your US visa allows you to enter the US and only the US.  It means nothing to the Canadian government.  You are a Brazilian citizen, so just like every other Brazilian citizen who wants to enter Canada, you need a Canadian visa. (There are a few exceptions in the world, mainly small tourist-oriented countries that will honor the visas of large countries, but that is the exception, not the rule.)

Comment: @NateEldredge:  there's also the Schengen area.  The idea of such an arrangement between Canada & the US gets floated from time to time, but has never gotten off the ground.

Comment: @NateEldredge US visas don't help people get into Canada, but US green cards do.

Answer (score 4):

As you hold a Brazilian passport, no you can not.

Here is a full list of [entry requirements to Canada by country](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp).

In general, having an American visa does not provide any entry privileges to Canada.